# Import External Symbol with Clang and WebAssembly

Tags: c++, c, clang, linker-errors, webassembly

When compiling C(++) code that has `extern` function declarations to WebAssembly with Clang, it gives `undefined reference` errors rather than importing the symbol. What option will make the linker add those as imports to the WebAssembly module instead of trying to resolve them?

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C" {
#endif

extern void externalFunction(void);

#ifdef __cplusplus
    }
#endif

int main() {
    externalFunction();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the import_module and import_name clang attributes to mark the function as imported. e.g.:

```
__attribute__((import_module("env"), import_name("externalFunction"))) void externalFunction(void);
```

Or you can pass --allow-undefined to the linker.  See https://lld.llvm.org/WebAssembly.html#imports.

Comment: Those attributes aren't working for me with clang 10.0.0. What version where they introduced?

Comment: Actually still doesn't work with clang 14.0.0. Is there some parameter that needs to be passed for it to work? I'm compiling to llvm, not straight to wasm, maybe that's it.

Comment: Ah I just had to pass `--target=wasm32`. Works on clang 10 now.